# Converting a cdecl function call from C to Pascal that uses callback with variable argument lists

Tags: c, delphi, header-files, pascal

I am converting a C header file for a video encoder DLL to Delphi Pascal.

I've run into some issues with access violations with the following function and need help resolving this:

```
h264venc_tt * MC_EXPORT_API h264OutVideoNew(
  void * (MC_EXPORT_API * get_rc)(const char* name),
  const struct h264_v_settings * set,
  int32_t options,
  int32_t CPU,
  int32_t frame0,
  int32_t nframes);
```

Note: MC_EXPORT_API = cdecl

The get_rc is declared as follows:

```
// resource functions dispatcher
void * MC_EXPORT_API get_rc(const char* name)
{
  if (!strcmp(name, "err_printf"))
    return (void*) error_printf;
  else if (!strcmp(name, "prg_printf"))
    return (void*) progress_printf;
  else if (!strcmp(name, "wrn_printf"))
    return (void*) warn_printf;
  else if (!strcmp(name, "inf_printf"))
    return (void*) info_printf;
  return NULL;
}
```

This function returns a pointer to another function that has a Variable Argument list. One of these is declared as this:

```
void error_printf(const char * fmt, ...)
{
  char lst[256];
  va_list marker;
  va_start(marker,fmt);
  vsprintf(lst,fmt,marker);
  va_end(marker);
  printf("%s\n", lst);
}
```

I've translated this the function call and the get_rc to this Delphi Pascal code:

```
PErrorMessageHandler = function (const Name: String): Pointer; cdecl varargs;

function h264OutVideoNew(
  get_rc: PErrorMessageHandler;
  settings: Ph264_v_settings;
  options: int32;
  CPU: int32;
  frame0: int32;
  nFrames: int32
): Pointer; cdecl; external 'mc_enc_avc.dll' index 4;
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement the C-style method error_printf shown above. 
Can anyone help to point me in the right direction? I am also curious if I have implemented the other functions correctly as I am getting access violations when I try to call the `h264OutVideoNew()` function.

PS! I've not included the packed record `Th264_v_settings`/`P_h264_v_settings` in this post as this is very long and not really the problem.

Comment: A final note: If I call h264OutVideNew(nil, Settings, 0, 0, 0, 0) the function call goes through with no errors so I am sure the problem lies with the get_rc function.

Comment: Do you need to write `error_printf` in Delphi and pass it to an external API function?

Comment: If your `Th264_v_settings` type contains any members of type `string` or `char`, then it very much **is** part of the problem!

Comment: I think error_print is similar to "procedure error_print(const fmt: PChar; const args: array of const|TVarRec);"

Comment: Don't use `<code>`. Indent. Also, no need for `<br/>`.

Comment: Apologies for my use of <code>, <br> and indentation. I am not very well versed with the use of StackOverflow. I will not do this again, promise!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A C parameter of type `char*` is a pointer to a null-terminated array of 8 bit characters. In Delphi the equivalent type is `PAnsiChar`. You cannot use `string` since that is a managed Delphi type that has no equivalent in C.

In addition, the error function prototype has void return value. You are returning a pointer and that's an error.

The bigger problem that you have is that you cannot readily implement a C style function that receives a variable number of arguments in Delphi. You can declare and call such a function, but you cannot implement one. This means that such a function, with variable arguments, has to be an [external function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Procedures_and_Functions#External_Declarations).

Now, you could write your own assembler routine to full off the variable arguments. However, that's not the route I would take. I would write the function in C and then compile it to a .obj file that can be linked into your Delphi program with `$LINK`.

If you don't actually need to read off the variable arguments, you can ignore them like this:

```
TErrorMessageHandler = procedure(Name: PAnsiChar); cdecl;
```

Note that I have made the following changes:

1. Change the type name to be prefixed with `T` which is standard.
2. Corrected the type of the `Name` parameter.
3. Changed from function to procedure to match the C declaration.
4. Removed the `varargs` which we cannot implement in Delphi and thus ignore the additional parameters.

Then your imported function would look like this:

```
function h264OutVideoNew(
  get_rc: TErrorMessageHandler;
  settings: Ph264_v_settings;
  options: int32;
  CPU: int32;
  frame0: int32;
  nFrames: int32
): Pointer; cdecl; external 'mc_enc_avc.dll' index 4;
```

And then you can implement the error callback function like this:

```
procedure error_printf(Name: PAnsiChar); cdecl;
begin
  // do stuff here
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to implement `error_printf`. If you can let me know what you want your implementation of that to do, I can add some more details to the answer. For example, do you want to format the message and send it to some function in your Delphi program? Or do you just want to write the message on `stdout` or `stderr`?

Comment: I was simply trying to convert a sample application written i C to Delphi. The get_rc function in C returns a (void*) pointer to a callback function based on the input parameter name. (See above). The different callback functions does different things, the error_printf being the simplest one of them.

Comment: After implementing your suggested changes, the function is called successfully and I can step into the get_rc error handler implemented as procedure(Name: PAnsiChar): Pointer; cdecl. The procedure is called with different values and I've tried to return a pointer to the error_printf() procedure but it is never called. I will look into your suggestion of using C (C++Builder) to create an .obj file I can link to my application instead.

Comment: You can use BCC55 freely downloadable if you don't have CPPBuilder.

Comment: What did you mean by *I would write the function in C* ? What would you write there ? I cannot somehow make sense of this (being in the same situation).

Comment: @TLama You can't implement a varargs function in Delphi. It needs to be implemented in C or C++.

Comment: So you mean implement that callback in C lang., where I process the variadic parameter and dispatch it in a different (non-variadic) form through another (implementable) callback into my Delphi app. ?